# How can I view a git log of just one user's commits?

Tags: git, version-control, git-log

When using `git log`, how can I filter by user so that I see only commits from that user?

Comment: Is there a way to see the same thing directly on `github`?

Comment: To do this on github: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23515164/26510

Answer (score 2283, accepted):

This works for both `git log` and [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk) - the 2 most common ways of viewing history.
You don't need to use the whole name:

```
git log --author="Jon"
```

will match a commit made by "Jonathan Smith"

```
git log --author=Jon
```

and

```
git log --author=Smith
```

would also work. The quotes are optional if you don't need any spaces.

**Add `--all` if you intend to search all branches and not just the current commit's ancestors in your repo.**

You can also easily match on multiple authors as regex is the underlying mechanism for this filter. So to list commits by Jonathan or Adam, you can do this:

```
git log --author="\(Adam\)\|\(Jon\)"
```

In order to exclude commits by a particular author or set of authors using regular expressions as noted [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word), you can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in combination with the `--perl-regexp` switch:

```
git log --author='^(?!Adam|Jon).*$' --perl-regexp
```

Alternatively, you can exclude commits authored by Adam by using `bash` and piping:

```
git log --format='%H %an' | 
  grep -v Adam | 
  cut -d ' ' -f1 | 
  xargs -n1 git log -1
```

If you want to exclude commits commited (but not necessarily authored) by Adam, replace `%an` with `%cn`. More details about this are in my blog post here: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/07/18/filtering-by-author-name/

Comment: Is there a way to do the opposite? Say - I want to see all commits except for Jon's.

Comment: @Ian as for git help log "Jon" is a regular expression so it should be pretty easy

Comment: git log --format=%an | egrep -v 'Jon*' | xargs -n 1 git log -1

Comment: oops.. forget that. but you get the gist. get a "not in" functionality out of piping through egrep -v and other tricks on the command line.

Comment: On my instance of git, I needed to add the `-E` flag to get the 'multiple user' example above to work.  Wanted to make sure my experience isn't unique before I edit the answer

Comment: Is this command for the commits on the current branch only or is this for the entire project? How would be for the entire project?

Comment: you would add `--all` to have log list commits from all branches instead of just current commit's ancestors. Git implicitly runs `git log HEAD` when you issue `git log`.

Comment: Any way to make `gitk` leave out the parent commits from other authors? (They are shown with white circles.) In contrast, `git log --graph` doesn't show the parent commits; it only shows the given author's commits. I would love to see the same output in `gitk`. *(Already checked Preferences and Edit View - couldn't find anything useful.)*

Comment: @IanRobinson Another way to exclude certain committers -- PERL regular expressions support "negative look-ahead assertions". So, you can construct an expression that requires that the starting point not match an expression that matches another regexp anywhere later in the string. Example, to exclude all author strings that contain 'Jon': `git log --author='^(?!.*Jon)' --perl-regexp`

Comment: Oh, just noticed that a variation on that is further down in the original answer. Silly me :-)

Comment: Beware this is case sensitive

Comment: Add --no-merges if you want to exclude merge commits from that list.

Comment: I note that the following syntax seems to work also:  git log --author jeff  (that is, no equal sign).

Comment: Watch out for the quotation mark wrapping the pattern regex. Mine did not work since I used single quote(') instead of double quote (").

`git log --author='^(?!.*Charith)' --perl-regexp` did not work.
`git log --author="^(?!.*Charith)" --perl-regexp` did work

Comment: @ADTC: I asked separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219779/how-to-avoid-showing-parent-commits-in-gitk-when-filtering-by-author

Answer (score 90):

```
git log --author="that user"
```

Comment: How to make is exact seach? I don't want to see commits from "that user2"

Comment: it is all about proper naming in the system

Answer (score 55):

On github there is also a *secret* way...

You can filter commits by author in the commit view by appending param `?author=github_handle`. For example, the link https://github.com/dynjs/dynjs/commits/master?author=jingweno shows a list of commits to the Dynjs project

Comment: any way to see across branches? something like commits/all ?

Comment: How did you find this? What other flags are supported?

Comment: pro.mean's answer how to do this via the interface: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39123694/1225617

Comment: I don't prefer this answer because the question was related to a software and not related to a specific service.

Comment: Question was _just_ how to view the git log - regardless of technology. So this answer fits the bill just fine.

Comment: I find this a good answer this is helpful to some including me and withing the bounds of the question

Answer (score 36):

```
git help log
```

gives you the manpage of git log. Search for "author" there by pressing / and then typing "author", followed by Enter. Type "n" a few times to get to the relevant section, which reveals:

```
git log --author="username"
```

as already suggested.

Note that this will give you the author of the commits, but in Git, the author can be someone different from the committer (for example in Linux kernel, if you submit a patch as an ordinary user, it might be committed by another administrative user.) See [Difference between author and committer in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750808/difference-between-author-and-committer-in-git) for more details)

Most of the time, what one refers to as the user is both the committer and the author though.

Comment: @James I think your negativity here is unwarranted. I was simply trying to teach him how to look it up from the command line in case he forgets. I think you are mistaking me for a person who just says RTFM, but I included the answer in my response.

Comment: It's not negativity. It's the fact that people come here asking for advice, and a lot of folks want to respond with some variant of RTFM. Bodes poorly for the community.

Comment: @James I have to agree with ustun here. He *did* answer the question, *and* he offered a strategy for finding the answer which is helpful for finding answers to other git-related questions.

Comment: The reason there is a divergence of opinion here is because the statement, "Search for 'author' there" can be functionally replaced with "Use magic" as there is not a sensible reason to predict the keyword author over synonyms or abbreviations. Thus the perception of the RTFM response.

Comment: I don't think it's quite as black and white as this. Now, I agree with unstun that we ought to educate people how to do things for themselves - that's a good idea. Where unstun went slightly wrong is making the assumptions a) That the OP knows how to search a man page, and more importantly b) That the OP knows to search for 'author'. They may have searched for 'committer' or 'name' or something.

Comment: @JohnHunt you are right, it had never occurred to me to explain what search means and how it is done at the time. Kind of assumed it. Fixing the text slightly.

Answer (score 34):

To pull more details - (Here `%an` refers to author)

Use this :-

```
git log --author="username" --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s"
```

Comment: And if you want their Email address use format `%ae` instead of `%an` (which gave Name.)

Comment: `--author` actually searches by the author name and not committer name. I would change `"username"` to author

Comment: Syntax of [commit fields available in `--pretty=format`](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats#Documentation/pretty-formats.txt-emHem)

Answer (score 30):

If you want to filter your own commits:

```
git log --author="<$(git config user.email)>"
```

Comment: It also works without the quotes and brackets (at least on git bash and ubuntu bash).

Comment: Filtering by an email address like here has the advantages that (1) it does not get confused by authors using various names on various computers, and (2) it prevents the issue that filtering by "authorname" will also show results for "authorname2" etc..

Answer (score 23):

Since the other question was (possibly wrongfully so?) locked, I will just put this here:

**show authors with their commit counts:**

```
git shortlog -nse
```

**find all commits for specific USERNAME:**

```
git log --author=USERNAME --oneline --color=never | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git show
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. In case anybody else also wasn't getting any output for the `xargs git show` part, perhaps like me you need to add `--color=never` to the `git log` part (I forget that the color settings in my config sometimes mess other things up).

Answer (score 16):

```
cat | git log --author="authorName" > author_commits_details.txt
```

This gives your commits in text format.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `cat |`?

Comment: @KeithThompson To chase a mouse.

Answer (score 15):

try this tool
https://github.com/kamranahmedse/git-standup

### Usage

```bash
$ git standup [-a <author name>] 
              [-w <weekstart-weekend>] 
              [-m <max-dir-depth>]
              [-f]
              [-L]
              [-d <days-ago>]
              [-D <date-format>] 
              [-g] 
              [-h]
```

Below is the description for each of the flags

```
- `-a`      - Specify author to restrict search to (name or email)
- `-w`      - Specify weekday range to limit search to (e.g. `git standup -w SUN-THU`)
- `-m`      - Specify the depth of recursive directory search
- `-L`      - Toggle inclusion of symbolic links in recursive directory search
- `-d`      - Specify the number of days back to include
- `-D`      - Specify the date format for "git log" (default: relative)
- `-h`      - Display the help screen
- `-g`      - Show if commit is GPG signed or not
- `-f`      - Fetch the latest commits beforehand
```

Answer (score 11):

You can even abbreviate this a bit by simply using part of the user name:

```
git log --author=mr  #if you're looking for mrfoobar's commits
```

Answer (score 4):

If using GitHub:

- go to branch
- click on commits

it will show list in below format

```
branch_x: < comment> 
author_name committed 2 days ago
```

- to see individual author's commit ; click on *author_name*  and there you can see all the commit's of that author on that branch

Comment: That's a lot of clicks and assumes hosted git repo. Does not answer CLI as many above have done.

Comment: @lacostenycoder but it's useful information, especially as so many git projects are on GitHub!

Answer (score 4):

Show n number of logs for x user in colour by adding this little snippet in your .bashrc file.

```
gitlog() {
    if [ "$1" ] && [ "$2" ]; then
       git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09 %C(cyan)%an%x09 %Creset%ad%x09 %Cgreen%s" --date-order -n "$1" --author="$2"
    elif [ "$1" ]; then
       git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09 %C(cyan)%an%x09 %Creset%ad%x09 %Cgreen%s" --date-order -n "$1"
    else
        git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09 %C(cyan)%an%x09 %Creset%ad%x09 %Cgreen%s" --date-order
    fi
}

alias l=gitlog
```

To show the last 10 commits by Frank:

`l 10 frank`

To show the last 20 commits by anyone:

`l 20`

Answer (score 4):

Although, there are many useful answers. Whereas, just to add another way to it. You can also use

```
git shortlog --author="<author name>" --format="%h %s"
```

It will show the output in the grouped manner:

```
<Author Name> (5):
  4da3975f dependencies upgraded
  49172445 runtime dependencies resolved
  bff3e127 user-service, kratos, and guava dependencies upgraded
  414b6f1e dropwizard :- service, rmq and db-sharding depedencies upgraded
  a96af8d3 older dependecies removed
```

Here, total of 5 commits are done by `<Author Name>` under the current branch. Whereas, you can also use `--all` to enforce the search everywhere *(all the branches)* in the git repository.

**One catch:** git internally tries to match an input `<author name>` with the name and email of the author in the git database. It is *case-sensitive*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either = or "space".
For instance following two commands return the same

```
git log --author="Developer1"

git log --author "Developer1"
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative is using a tool called [mergestat](https://github.com/mergestat/mergestat) which lets you run SQL queries against the commit history in a repo (among other things).

```
mergestat "SELECT * FROM commits WHERE author_name LIKE '%Jon%'"
```

It's a bit more verbose but can offer flexibility in finding specifically what you're looking for in a generic way.

For instance, filtering out merge commits and only showing commits in the past year, from a specific author:

```
mergestat "SELECT * FROM commits WHERE author_name LIKE '%Jon%' WHERE author_when > DATE('now', '-1 year') AND parents < 2"
```

Full disclosure: I'm a maintainer of the project :)

Answer (score 0):

My case: I'm using source tree, I followed the following steps:

1. Pressed `CRL+3`
2. Changed dropdown authors
3. Typed the name "Vinod Kumar"

[image]