# Bitbucket user activity log

Tags: logging, android-activity, bitbucket

We are having a free(5 users) Bitbucket account and recently I gave write access to another user from another team. I have searched Bitbucket documentation but could not find as how to monitor another user activity( as whether he has cloned our repository and when). Can anybody help in this regard?

Answer (score 2):

Just use GIT commands. In BitBucket, in the top menu there is a "Terminal" button. Just click on it to open the terminal and then type any GIT command.

```
git log --author="JonDoe"
```

Will prompt the activity of the relevant user.

see [How can I view a git log of just one user's commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits)

Comment: This doesn't give user activity across all repositories.

Comment: or even branches

Comment: or who cloned it and when