# Git log without an author's commits

Tags: git

There's a project we're working on where the majority of commits are added in by a front-end developer.  He's editing mainly HTML, CSS, JavaScript files that are not related to the back-end work that I'm helping with.  It would be great if I could show the `git log` minus commits added by the front-end developer, so I could get a view of commits just related to the backend.

Is there an option I can pass to `git log` that would allow me to ***exclude*** all commits by an author? I just want to exclude this one developer's commits, ***I still care about viewing commits from other developers*** as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I view a git log of just one user's commits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits)

Comment: Hm... that seems like a solution to the opposite problem of the one I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Agreed, trojanfoe is wrong. You need something more specific.

Comment: @ElliotLarson: The accepted answer in the alleged duplicate contains information on how to solve the inverse problem.

Comment: @ElliotLarson Ah yeah, apologies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/406230/946850) [Negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will do just that, but you have to ask `git` to use `--perl-regexp`.

```
git log --author='^(?!krlmlr).*$' --perl-regexp
```

According to `git help log`,

> `--perl-regexp` ... requires libpcre to be compiled in.

Apparently, not all `git`s out there have this; for the one shipped with Ubuntu 13.04, this works out of the box.

Comment: So, this looks pretty elegant and is probably the correct answer. Unfortunately, my version of git wasn't compiled with pcre, so running the command gives me a related error message.  I don't have time right now to do the recompile, but I'll accept the answer.  I think the perl-regexp path is probably the right direction to go in.  Thanks.

Comment: @ElliotLarson: I'm on Ubuntu 13.04, works out of the box for me.

Comment: Hm, I installed git with Homebrew on my Mac.  I'll have to research why the Homebrew version doesn't come with pcre added in by default when it's standard on Ubuntu.  Sometimes, these things "fail" silently at compile time with Homebrew if there's funkiness on the system, meaning it's possible some Perl libraries weren't found in the expected places and the resulting compile flag was left off.

Comment: Awesome. In case you have more than one author you'd like to exclude, you can use `--author='^(?!(author1|author2)).*$'`

Answer (score 3):

```
git rev-list --format='%aN' --all \
| sed 'N;/\nauthorname$/d;s/commit \(.*\)/\n.*/\1/' \
| git log --stdin
```

and of course substitute whatever heads you want for `--all` above.

Edit: list/select/process pipelines like this are bread and butter, it's just how git (like a lot of unix tools) was built.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for some reason, although I'm a total noob with sed.  It could just be that this is really close to what I'm looking for, but I'm just not quite sed savvy enough to wrangle the command.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this article](http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/07/18/filtering-by-author-name/) explains it clearly. (Though it was mentioned under @trojanfoe link). Mainly, it says:

> However it’s tricky to exclude commits by a particular author or set of authors using regular expressions as noted here. Instead, turn to bash and piping you can exclude commits authored by Adam by:

```
git log --format='%H %an' |  # get a list of all commit hashes followed by the author name
grep -v Adam |             # match the name but return the lines that *don't* contain the name
cut -d ' ' -f1 |           # from this extract just the first part of the line which is commit ref
xargs -n1 git log -1       # call git log from that commit stopped after 1 commit
```

> A limitation of this is that some log options that you would want are not available such as --graph 
>   due to the mechanics of calling git log multiple times.

Comment: What exactly does "this article" explain? Please summarize -- only a link is not an answer.

Comment: I saw this article in my initial search.  This doesn't really solve my problem, unless I want to take the approach of naming all authors except for one, which isn't a great solution.  The resulting command would be ugly and error prone.  I could see myself creating an alias for it, and then every time we add someone new to the team, I have to update my alias, but not before running my alias and being briefly confused about why the commits for "Dave" (a new developer) aren't showing up.  I'd rather just exclude one author.

Comment: Merely posting a link without any relevant quotes is ***not*** a good answer. What if the link breaks in the future? Then the answer becomes completely useless. If you quote the relevant information from the link in your answer, then we'll still have the information available on Stack Overflow, even if the link breaks.

Comment: Sorry, guys - you concerns look reasonable, so I adjusted the answer. Though, not very helpful, because the author of the question already mentioned that he saw this approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's more flexible to use

```
git log -i --author="^((?!abc).)*$" --perl-regexp
```

instead of

```
git log -i --author="^(?!abc).*$" --perl-regexp
```

The difference is that the latter one only excludes authors starting with `abc`, i.e., author `abcddd`, but not `ddabcd` or `dddabc` etc, while the former one will exclude all of those examples ***:)*** See *Finding Lines Containing or Not Containing Certain Words* in [this post](https://www.regular-expressions.info/completelines.html)

I've tested these two with **Git** on **Windows 10**.

Comment: Apart from the negative `lookahead` way shown above, the negative `lookbehind` way also works with the same effect: `git log -i --author="^(.(?<!abc))*$" --perl-regexp`