# git show logs exclude some user or committer

Tags: git, git-log

I don't know how to do this

I try these already:

`git log -p --author="user" --not Sites/Web/Templates`

`git log -p --author="!user" Sites/Web/Templates`

still show log of that user. Help, please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits read the whole answer, it explains how to use negative lookahead (since the matching engine uses regex) for what you're trying to do

Comment: @asermax, when i use `git log --author="^(?!Adam|Jon).*$" --perl-regexp`, I get `sh: event not found: Adam|Jon).`. what i miss? I think I just need add `--perl-regexp`, then `--author="!user""` is good to go, right?

Comment: The message `event not found` is coming from your shell, which is trying to do its own thing with the exclamation point.  To make the shell pass the `!` on to `git`, prefix the `!` with a backslash: `git log ... \!...`

Comment: @torek, that exactlly fix the problem. Unfortunately, I am using msgit, and not compiled with USE_LIBPCRE. Is there a window version support this? :)