# Get all file name committed by a user for a branch

Tags: git

Is there a way to know every file a user has commited for a specific branch?

I tried

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r dev_3.9
```

but they don't have any user option.

a search a way to 
  for branch 3.9 what file bob has done a commit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I view a git log of just one user's commits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits)

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/424071

Comment: i have already checked this links, its don't answer to the question.

Comment: Yes, but surely they point you in the right direction.