# Git "pseudo-manual" merge a user's work

Tags: git

I have, due to various previous issues, renames, server changes, Xcode mishandling, etc, **rewritten the history** of my branch(es) *using the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/change-the-current-branch-to-master-in-git).*

However, one of my colleagues has uncommitted work from a branch that is currently not very compatible with the one the other people use. What I'd like is to be able to grab all the commits he's done from a trusted date and pull them in the correct branch(to save history)

I can **show a log of my colleague's work** *using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits),* which would allow me, in the worst case, to grab manually every change and cherry pick the correct source from the latest version, knowing every change he made.

Can I actually filter from a given commit, since I know the hash of the commit he made when he started to work on the functionality we don't want to lose?

In order to see what I'm doing, I've added a prettifying option `--pretty=format:"%H - %ad : %s"`.

I know there are tools, such as  --since and --until, but when I do `git log --author="colleagueLogin" --pretty=format:"%H - %ad : %s" --since commitHash`, I get all his commits ever, so obviously, I'm doing it wrong.

Thanks to Twalberg's help, I understood I could skip the "making a clean log" step, and integrate the commits (which I now have clearly listed) by applying *human intelligence* to the list I have, e.g. start the cherry-picking process on the correct date. However, for the sake of knowledge, I'd still love to learn how to cut off `git log --author="colleagueLogin" --pretty=format:"%H - %ad : %s"` from the commit date I know he started the feature he worked on...

Comment: Is `git cherry-pick <his-first-commit>..<his-last-commit>` what you are looking for? You could achieve something similar with `git format-patch`/`git am`, but that's more work...

Comment: Actually, I'd like to have all his work in a nicely packaged patch to apply to the existing code base in our branch, but I'm afraid it's a bit too complex for my git-skills. I looked into git diff, but I could not figure out how to pass it the arguments of my `git log`, and anyway the later do not work. I also tried adding HEAD~numberOfCommits, or --since='<date commitHash>'..HEAD or --since='<date shortCommitHash>'..HEAD, but it doesn't list the commits I want. I'm reading through git format-patch now, thanks for the pointer!