# Git - List files created by author

Tags: git, logging

Is there a way to list files created by a specific author using **Git**?
I also need to filter these results, either by filename (regex/pattern) or folder where they were created.

So what I'm looking for is a list of created (not updated) files by author without filename duplication and without commit messages.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits

Comment: What I want to do is a bit more complicated than a `git log author=foobar`. The closest I found yet is `git whatchanged --author="foobar" --name-only --oneline`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

List all commits adding files, showing the commit author and the added files; then paste the author to the front of each file listed:

```
# add `--author=pattern` to the log arguments to restrict by author
# add anything you like to the `--format=` template
# add any restrictions you like to the `/^A\t/` selector in the awk,
#     ... say /^A\t/ && /\.c$/ { etc.

git log --name-status --diff-filter=A --format='> %aN' \
| awk '/^>/ {tagline=$0}
       /^A\t/ {print tagline "\t" $0}'
```

Comment: Perfect: `git log --author="Vadorequest" --name-status --diff-filter=A --format='> %aN' | awk '/^>/ {tagline=$0} /^A\t/ {print tagline "\t" $0}'`. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
$ git whatchanged --author="yourAthor" --name-only
```

And also here you have some filters

http://gitref.org/inspect/

Comment: Closer, but I don't want to see it by commit, neither the commit message and without filename duplication. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
git whatchanged --author="AuthorName" --name-only --oneline | grep FilePath | sort | uniq -c
```