# View all the changes pushed by a user in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have setup a gerrit server for code review for a git repo. 
Whenever I do `git push origin master` the push is successful but the changes are not being displayed on gerrit web page under `My -> Changes` tab . Only the changes that were pushed to `HEAD:ref/for/master`  branch are being displayed.
So how can I display all the pushes to the gerrit server on gerrit web page?

Answer (score 1):

Changes pushed without the `refs/for/` prefix are pushed directly into the target branch without a Gerrit review.

You can display commits by author with plain Git commands; see: [How can I view a git log of just one user's commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits)

Comment: I want to find the commits by author in gerrit web page . Is it possible?

Comment: You can only find changes in Gerrit which are reviewed in Gerrit.