# Create branch / pull request with only my commits

Tags: git, version-control

I made new branch from `master` called `feature1`.

It took me more than one month and in between that I did 3-4 merge and 1-2 rebase with master. Now my branch shows commits from all authors.

The senior coder wants to review what i did in my branch with only my 25 commits as all other commits by others are already in master.

However, when I create pull request then it also shows commits by others as well and it's hard to check only the work I did.

Is there any way that I can create some pull request which only highlights my commits so that he can view which files changed etc?

Comment: Related, though not duplicate, question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits

Answer (score 0):

You could probably filter your branch to only your commits but it's probably easier to just filter the list of commits shown to you like `git log --author='<username'`

If the branch is on GitHub, you can do something like `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/commits?author=<username>`

Comment: I want to create a pull request of some sort that can show the,  all the files i have changed in my branch  without other users commit

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing may generate a not working version. What is worse, it is possible to have conflicts because you made changes in parts that now you do not have.

The senior coder should be smart enough to know techniques to filter the work of each developer.

He could use frontend application like these [guis](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis): gitk, smartGit, git-cola.

You can do it too from the terminal with [git-log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
git log --author='<username'
```