# How to find a specific git author

Tags: git, author

I'm trying to find all commits made by Matt, but in my repository there are a couple of users with similar names (e.g., Matthew), and `git log --author="Matt"` covers these users that are not Matt.

Is there a way to say to git do not be that smart and filter only the string that I'm looking for?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits

Comment: Not actually. The solutions proposed have the same problems that I mentioned here.

Comment: Then I don't think there is any other better way to do that using git commands. Probably you can use some shell command for that.

Comment: How about piping the output from git into `grep`?

Comment: Other way around is in GUI, click the author's username from anywhere in the commit history, and the commits you can see filtered commits by that author's username

Comment: GUI will not help much, because I need to do this on thousand of commits. The --author flag supports regular expressions. But `--author="^Matt$"` does not work, although it works on grep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read [this answer carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4262780/2240141), and the [git log docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html), you could do that either by:

- using `-F` flag (which treats the string as a string to look for, not a pattern), or
- using `-E` flag along with a regexp

Note that to do that, you have to think of the `author` as the **full author name**, which I believe is the same, that git log without filtering prints.

Using -F flag (I checked it for me and it worked):

```
$ git log -F --author='Matt <matt@matts.email.com>'
```

Using regexp:

```
$ git log -E --author='^Matt\s<(.+)>$'
```

I tested both on my git console, and both worked.

Comment: Great. I didn't know about the -F and -E flags.