# How to get a list of all modified files by a user and move the files to a new branch?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'd like to know how can I get a list of all files that a particular user had edited since it started do commit and push in the repository.

I need to do that because this user should have created a new branch for its modifications but it didn`t do that so I need do find a way to solve this.

:)

Comment: Check out [ask].  what have you tried? what research have you done?

Comment: Ah, ok! I'm going to edit with my tries. Thank You.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits

Comment: It's not a duplicate! this only lists the commits I need a way to see all the files under this commits and a way to move them to a new branch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log --name-only --oneline --author user > changed_files_tmp.txt`

For each commit there will be record:

```
7ac4432 Bug 100 Try to fix
file1
file2
dir/file3
```

You need to delete lines with commit messages ( I hope you have some pattern in commit messages ) and you have list of files, changed by this user. In this case I assume, that all commits have `Bug` in commit message and there is no `Bug` file:

`cat changed_files_tmp.txt | grep -v Bug | sort | uniq > changed_files.txt`