# Get User Commit Detail in Java

Tags: java, github, egit, github-api

I have created a Java application that performs Github authentication. It then returns the access token.

I can list all of the repositories from this access token, but I wanted to know if there is any way I can get the currently logged in user's commit list using Eclipse's egit plugin.

Any information regarding this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This works for both git log and gitk - the 2 most common ways of viewing history. You don't need to use the whole name.

```
git log --author="Jon"
```

will match a commit made by "Jonathan Smith"

```
git log --author=Jon
```

I'm not sure about eGit though.  The documentation states...

```
Click Team > Show in History from the context menu to inspect the history of a resource:
```

Ref: [eGit documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Inspect_History)

See here : [StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits)