# for git how to view all commits made in a repo?

Tags: git

I am trying to view all the commits I have ever made. I am on one branch.

i've tried `git log --since=2.weeks` but that hasn't worked like the docs say it should. A bit confused.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits

Comment: Try `git log --first-parent BRANCHNAME --since="2 weeks ago"`

Comment: Can you clarify the question? You say you want "all commits made in a repo" and also "I am on one branch". So do you want all the commits _in that branch_, or all of the commits in the repo, that is to say, all commits from _all_ branches?

Comment: so to be 100 percent clear. I am on one branch because I only have one branch. And yes I want to see all commits from today till when I initialized the repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a flag to list all commits: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---all

```
git log --all
```

you probably want to use together with `--oneline` flag

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
git log --oneline //See all the commit
```

and

```
git log --oneline -n <how many line commit you see>

for example :
      git log --oneline -n 5
```