# How to avoid showing parent commits in gitk when filtering by author?

Tags: git, git-log, gitk

I want to show only my commits in gitk. I try to use the command

```
gitk --author="Eugeniy Maksimov" <path>
```

gitk shows not only my commits, but also theirs parents. Why? How to avoid this?

Comment: The short answer to "why" is because `gitk` adds `--boundary` to the arguments it passes to `git log` / `git rev-list`. But why it does *that*, and how you might modify `gitk` to avoid that without breaking it (if a simple "remove `--parents`" breaks it in the first place, which I don't know is true), I don't know.